# Criando um arquivo a partir de uma lista e varios arquivos diferentes

Tags: awk, grep

Eu tenho uma lista de nomes e vários arquivos diferentes que podem ou não conter todos os nomes na lista e um valor atribuído aos nomes. Eu preciso comparar os valores de todos estes cada arquivo para os nomes na lista.
Estes são o tipo de arquivos txt eu tenho

List

```
Alligator mississippiensis
Anas platyrhynchos
Anolis carolinensis
Chrysemys picta
Columba livia
Gallus gallus
```

File1

```
Alligator mississippiensis 2546
Anas platyrhynchos 32
Columba livia 21571
Gallus gallus 226
```

File2

```
Anas platyrhynchos 2
Anolis carolinensis 3255
Chrysemys picta 225
Columba livia 2215
Gallus gallus 22548
```

E esse e o formato do output que eu preciso, onde a primeira linha seria o nome dos arquivos, indicando de onde os valores vieram...

```
List File1, File2
Alligator mississippiensis 2546,0
Anas platyrhynchos 32,2
Anolis carolinensis 0,3255
Chrysemys picta 0,225
Columba livia 21571, 2215
Gallus gallus 226, 22548
```

Eu pensei em algo como grep e encontrando o nome da lista no arquivo, imprimir coluna 2, se nao encontrar imprimir 0..

Alguem pode ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que tenhas um awk recente (Exemplo GNU-awk dos sistemas linux)

```
awk '    { a[$1 " " $2][FILENAME]=$3}
     END { printf("0: Animais %s, %s\n", ARGV[2], ARGV[3]);
           for (x in a ){
              printf("%s %d,%d\n", x, a[x][ARGV[2]], a[x][ARGV[3]])}
         }' lista f1 f2
```

Esta solução pode alterar a ordem dos animais. Eventualmente `...| sort`

**EDIT**: se tivermos um variável número de ficheiros, podemos por exemplo:

```
awk '    { a[$1 " " $2][FILENAME]=$3}
     END { printf("0: Animais"); 
           for(i=2; i< ARGC; i++) printf(",%s ",ARGV[i]); 
           printf("\n");
           for (x in a ){
              printf("%s", x); 
              for(i=2; i< ARGC; i++) printf(",%d",a[x][ARGV[i]]);
              printf("\n");}
         }' lista f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 .......
```

Comment: Obrigada Joao, funcionou perfeitamente para 2 arquivos, mas eu tenho 600... To tentando editar aqui, mas a ajuda e sempre bem vinda!

Comment: @silvia, E pretendes escrever 600 colunas diferentes?

Comment: Sim, esse eh meu tamanho amostral (por isso o desespero... rs)

Comment: Mas eu ja consegui uma solucao no forum em ingles... vou postar o link. Muito obrigada!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853049/combining-several-text-files-in-a-comparative-way/43855774#43855774

Comment: Chegaste a ver s soluçao que eu proposto ontem?